# Writing send_all and recv_all functions for sockets in C

Tags: c, sockets, io

I am a new C programmer and so you will have to excuse my lack of knowledge. I am trying to use sockets in C on a windows machine to send data back and forth between a client and server. I am using the tools of cygwin with the codeblocks IDE.  Simple send and receives were not working and so after some searching I was under the impression my problem was I needed a send_all and recv_all function. I have written the following two functions but receive seems to always get stuck in an infinite loop. I am not really sure why.

```
void send_all(int socket, void *buffer, int length) {
    size_t i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i += send(socket, buffer, length - i, 0)){
        printf("Completed: %d bytes \r", i);
    }
    printf("Send Completed: %d bytes \n", length);
}

void recv_all(int sockfd, void *buffer, int length){
    size_t i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i+= recv(sockfd, buffer + i, length - i, 0)){
        printf("Completed: %d bytes \r", i);
    }
    printf("Receive Completed: %d bytes \n", length);
}
```

I am wondering if it is because the receive doesn't know how many bytes the send is sending it. All advice is appreciated but please keep it constructive. Thanks.

Comment: @user376507, it's length bytes.  `read/recv` doesn't null terminate or anything like that.

Comment: @user376507 Thanks all good points. I will look up TLV because I don't know what that is. I am not sending length ahead of time I was just using the whole length of my buffer which in retrospect doesn't make sense because shorter sends will cause it never to end.

Comment: @ user376507 wrong, `recv` returns when any non-zero amount of data is available

Comment: @TheCount Refer to the following wiki for details on TLV http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type-length-value

Comment: @Duck thank you for the correction. I will modify my comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`recv()` actually returns a *signed* value (`int` in Winsock, `ssize_t` in POSIX). Its return value can be a negative number if a read error occurred, OR if the socket is in non-blocking mode and no data is available. Its return value is zero if the socket was closed gracefully (this would cause an infinite loop in your code).

You will need to check the return value before you add it to your byte counter, to detect both of these conditions.

If your socket is in blocking mode (the default), your code will block indefinitely until the required amount of data has been received, or an error occurs (once you add code to check for that). Given the name of your function this seems to be the behavior you want. If so, your general approach is sound.

```
ssize_t bytesRead = 0;

while (bytesRead < length)
{
    ssize_t rv = recv(/* ... */);

    if (rv == 0)
    {
        printf("Socket closed gracefully before enough data received\n");
        break;
    }

    else if (rv < 0)
    {
        // if your socket is non-blocking, check for EAGAIN which
        // would mean no data is currently available; in this case you
        // could do something like call select() on the socket to
        // go to sleep until more data comes in

        printf("Read error occurred before enough data received\n");
        break;
    }

    bytesRead += rv;
}
```